# Why is blender frozen after a few minutes from opening?

Tags: error

Whenever I open Blender, after about a minute or two, it stops working. It doesn't crash, it just sits there loading indefinitely. I can hit the minimize button, the window button, and the close button, but I cannot do anything on Blender itself. At first, Blender ran just fine. Then recently, it would occasionally take a few seconds to do some actions every once in a while, sometimes it would stop when I rotated, sometimes when I selected, but never with any consistency or often enough to be a problem. But today, It suddenly stopped working all together. I have been trying for the past four hours to get it working, updating everything, deleting unnecessary files, closing and reopening Blender, but nothing worked. I know it's not the file size because it's only 2.5 MB and my computer has handled much larger files with ease, and it's not something else eating up the memory, because I am currently using about the same amount of memory as I was earlier today, and yesterday, and the day before, and the day before. But for whatever reason, it crashed today. If anyone can help me, I would be very greatful.

Comment: So it doesn't crash, but it crashed today or does it just freeze? Autosave happens every 2 minutes only if the file is changed. It goes to `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\` on Windows. I think if the disk runs out of memory or for some other reason Blender cannot save to that location(if it's set in the Preferences) this might happen. Other then that, some addon may be broken, try backing up your user preferences and loading Factory Settings(File->Defaults->load Factory Settings). then you can turn your addons one by one to see which one is the problem.

Comment: I have no addons

Comment: I don't think it's really possible to tell what the problem is with the given information. Check everything that is different from a regular PC and regular Blender setup, because Blender does not do that. It's not a frequent issue. If you had your PC setup in a way that the OS is installed on a small partition of your disk, since Blender uses OS temp folder for autosaves, it is very possible the OS partition might run out of space and autosaves sort of match your description - they happen every few minutes, "never with any consistency" - only if the file is changed.